# Google Sheets query function needing to provide 0 value for no value found

Tags: google-sheets, null, average, vlookup, google-query-language

The query function looks at a separate sheet with orders entered by a dealer.  In some months the dealer may not have a order. The B:B column in current sheet is all the dealers in Ascending order. Then I have separate columns for by month view with 3 columns per month. Number of contracts, amount then average.  My query calculates correctly, but if a dealer doesn't have a contract then it skips.  So my list is out of order. I'm needing it to place a 0 if no value found.  I have 2 versions of the query.
J = amount, H = Dealer name, A = Date, the B = is the dealer list in current sheet.
This query populates but out of order due to skipping NUll or NA.

```
=QUERY('2021ContractsData'!A:V,
"Select COUNT(J),SUM(J),AVG(J)
 WHERE MONTH(A)+1=1
 Group By H LABEL COUNT(J) 'Contracts',SUM(J) 'Amount',AVG(J) 'Average'")
```

This query populates nothing, it shows the Header names but no values in rows.

```
=QUERY('2021ContractsData'!A:V,
"Select COUNT(J),SUM(J),AVG(J)
 WHERE MONTH(A)+1=1
 AND H='"&B2:B&"'
 Group By H LABEL COUNT(J) 'Contracts',SUM(J) 'Amount',AVG(J) 'Average'")
```

[Google Sheet View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO5kE.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Please see link below.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3ZjzrHdCTX9Y8fml6VwdJ4QATSbBhGMzy3a6sgSNfg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in C2:

```
={"Contracts", "Amount", "Average"; 
 INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B3:B, QUERY('2021ContractsData'!A:V,
 "select H,count(J),sum(J),avg(J) 
  where month(A)+1=1 
  group by H"), {2,3,4}, 0), 0))}
```

Comment: TY very much for the time and expertise player0, that worked.  How can I get 0's for blank spaces?

Comment: @geneavone answer updated for zeros.